# How do I compile C++ files from the command-line on Windows with VC++2008?

Tags: visual-c++, command-line

I'm curious to find a way to compile `.cpp` files from the Windows command prompt. Is there a way to do so with Visual Studio? The only compiler I've got is VC++2008.  So can I define VC++ to be my system's compiler?

Comment: What as MS-DOS to do with anything? Do you know what MS-DOS is?

Comment: i just want to say windows terminal. My mistake!

Comment: cl.exe is able to run from the command prompt.

Comment: @KerrekSB, edited title since obviously this has nothing to do with MS-DOS.

Comment: I want to compile cpp from command prompt not to run the executable.

Answer (score 5):

There is *Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt* item under the start menu item *All Programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 -> Visual Studio Tools*. It will launch a command prompt with the environment correctly configured to enable you to run `cl.exe`, `link.exe`, etc.

Some useful links:

- [Compiler Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s7c9wdw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [Linker Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0zzbyt4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)